# Right path to CPP SDK for using it in IntelliJ Idea's cpp-project

Tags: c++, sdk, intellij

I can't find the right path to CPP SDK which is required by IntelliJ Idea, IDE that I want to use for developing a C++ project. Could someone show me the right place?

[image]

Comment: What in the nine hells do you mean by 'C++ SDK'? On a linux system there's `g++`. It compiles C++ and has all the default (linux development headers). Also `g++` should be by default on your `$PATH`.

Comment: @Wolfer if you look at the picture that klimat has joined in his post, the IntelliJ idea c++ plugin is **clearly** asking for a 'Cpp sdk home path'.

Comment: Did you manage to get it fixed, @klimat ?

Answer (score -1):

If your `gcc` is `/usr/bin/gcc`, I have set it to `/usr/bin`.

The only way to run is right click on main `cpp` file and say `compile the cpp`.

This compiles as well as runs the `a.out` file.